# Compiler error for dll import c++/MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, clr, dllimport

I have an MFC project that imports a C type DLL for use. This code worked fine when my project was in V 6.0, but after transferring the code to v2010 and adding some .NET code to the project(using \clr) that section of my code has started throwing compiler errors about missing ")" and ";". I have been researching all morning but I have not been able to come up with a solution. Can anyone please help me?

Below is the line section of code throwing the compiler error:

```
 #ifdef __cplusplus
  extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) void _stdcall KILLIT();
  extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) void _stdcall MAINDLL(char *PATH,int PATHLEN,char      *SUBDIR,int SUBDIRLEN, char *NAME,
int NAMELEN,char *HOMEDIR,int HOMEDIRLEN,char *ARCHDIR,int ARCHDIRLEN, int *FUN,int   *VERSION,int *BUS,int *PJMPV,
int *NFLAG,int *RETERROR);

#endif
```

These are the compiler errors I get:

```
DSAANA.cpp(32): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before 'constant'
>DSAANA.cpp(32): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'constant'
>DSAANA.cpp(34): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

I will appreciate any help I can get

Thanks 
Robby

Comment: Would be helpful if you added line numbers to each line so we know what is what.  Might be a name conflict with a macro in one of the headers.  For your function declarations, you could remove variable names and just have the variable types.  If that fixes one of the errors, slowly add your old variable names back in until you get the error again and you will find the conflict.

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson, thanks for the recommendation. Your advice helped me locate the error. Like you suggested it was a name conflict between one of the input parameters and a macro in one the headers. Thanks a million. I suggest you post your response as an answer so you can get the credit you deserve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be helpful if you added line numbers to each line so we know what is what. Might be a name conflict with a macro in one of the headers. For your function declarations, you could remove variable names and just have the variable types. If that fixes one of the errors, slowly add your old variable names back in until you get the error again and you will find the conflict.

Comment: Macros are generally defined in all caps so they won't conflict with other names in the program. Creating function and parameter names in all caps defeats the purpose and invites conflicts - this should be avoided.